# How to extract video from bag file?

Tags: ros, bagfile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I followed the tutorial [http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data] about extracting video from bag file. I create a launch file like this

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag" args="play -d 2 $(find image_view)/Data/test1.bag"/>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="node">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

But than got the following error

`ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rosbag/rosbag]: can't locate node [rosbag] in package [rosbag`]

Im using ROS Fuerte and Ubuntu 10.4. Any help??

This is my bag file info

version:     2.0
duration:    1:32s (92s)
start:       Apr 01 2011 14:17:41.82 (1301627861.82)
end:         Apr 01 2011 14:19:14.15 (1301627954.15)

```
size:        260.5 MB
messages:    6530
compression: none [284/284 chunks]
types:       sensor_msgs/Image     [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
             sensor_msgs/Imu       [6a62c6daae103f4ff57a132d6f95cec2]
             sensor_msgs/LaserScan [90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369]
topics:      /camera/image_raw   1135 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image    
             /imu/data           1802 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Imu      
             /scan               3593 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44777/how-to-extract-video-from-bag-file?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-09-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-29**:
How best to extract video depends on what you want to do with it. Please edit your question to provide that information. (Your time-stamp question was asked and answered separately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding your first question:

> I would like to know how to extract video from the bagfile?

I would recommend reading [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data) from from ROS image_view wiki page.

**Update:**

I summarized the steps needed to create the video in this tutorial: [How to extract images from a rosbag file and convert them to video](http://coderwall.com/p/qewf6g)

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-10-01**:
I already done the tutorial and got an Error. I posted that in edit question. Any help??

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-10-01**:
There seems to be a mistake on the wiki page (I just fixed it).  The correct string in the `rosbag` tag entry is `type="play"`

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-10-01**:
Still not working. I go this error. [FATAL] [1349151684.419671013]: Error opening file: play
process[extract-3]: started with pid [5008]
[ INFO] [1349151684.550808285]: Initialized sec per frame to 0.100000
[rosbag-2] process has died [pid 4996, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rosbag/bin/play

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2012-10-01**:
I updated my answer with a link to steps that I usually use.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-10-01**:
Sorry. Where did you updated the answer?? On the wiki page??Sorry I saw. But Im using ROS Fuerte and Ubuntu 10.4 and I got the following error.  Couldn't find package mjpeg-tools

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2012-10-01**:
I think the name for 10.04 used to be `mjpegtools`: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+package/mjpegtools

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-10-01**:
Ok. But have problems with rosrun image_view extract_images _sec_per_frame:=0.01 . So First I execute osrun image_view extract_images sec_per_frame:=0.01. Yes?? Than image:=. What means IMAGETOPICINBAGFILE???When I put the image path I got an error

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-10-01**:
And after rosrun image_view extract_images _sec_per_frame:=0.01  I got [ WARN] [1349156876.990156648]: extract_images: image has not been remapped! Typical command-line usage:
$ ./extract_images image:= [transport]

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-10-01**:
Ok. It works. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I wrote a python script that will directly output a video file from a ros bag without the need to convert them to images first.
https://github.com/mlaiacker/rosbag2video

This tool will also convert the images to a fixed frame rate to get a real-time video.

You need to have avconv installed!

just type:

`./rosbag2video.py yourbag.bag`

and you will get a video file  `<topic>.mp4` with 25 fps and h264 encoded

---

Originally posted by [mlaiacker](https://answers.ros.org/users/25537/mlaiacker/) with karma: 21 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2